# How to automatically join Galera Cluster when Scaling on Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, mariadb, galera

We currently utilize Microsoft Azure to host a MariaDB 10.1 Galera Cluster hosted on two VM's set with a Load Balancer. This functions well for our NORMAL operations, however, we would like to utilize Azure's autoscaling ability to spin up new nodes in the Galera Cluster when necessary. We have unscheduled excessive load at times which is too much for even our current cluster. It would be amazing if we had the ability to scale up as needed and then scale down when done.

Being that Galera is pre-configured with specific IP, is there any way to have the new instances that would be spun up, join the Load Balancer and Galera Cluster?

Comment: which address are you talking about when you say "is pre-configured with specific IP"?  Any new node only needs an address any cluster member to join the cluster.  Also, you should be careful when spinning up new instances since it will most likely need to do an SST which can affect the cluster.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this. We went ahead and moved to Linode due to IOPS issues anyways =D.